# Silhouette Method: The score is overall increasing as number of K increases

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

Unlike the tutorials online, where the silhouette plot has global maximum. My plot is overall increasing as number of K increases. But I could find local maximums. Should I do that?

I also used the elbow method. However, the curve is flat and is hard to determine the elbow.

Comment: check this out, if you find it useful. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10540/how-to-interpret-mean-of-silhouette-plot

Answer (score 1):

One thing that helps me to figure out the K is to run Affinity Propagation.  This will determine the optimal K for you, so you don't have to guess.  See the example below.

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.5,
                            random_state=0)

# #############################################################################
# Compute Affinity Propagation
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-50).fit(X)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, metric='sqeuclidean'))

# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

plt.close('all')
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    class_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = X[cluster_centers_indices[k]]
    plt.plot(X[class_members, 0], X[class_members, 1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
    for x in X[class_members]:
        plt.plot([cluster_center[0], x[0]], [cluster_center[1], x[1]], col)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()


# Result:

Estimated number of clusters: 3
Homogeneity: 0.872
Completeness: 0.872
V-measure: 0.872
Adjusted Rand Index: 0.912
Adjusted Mutual Information: 0.871
Silhouette Coefficient: 0.753
```

[image]

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py

It should be a trivial exercise to add in the Affinity Propagation library, feed your data into that, get the optimal K, and add that number to your K-Means algo.  Or, just go with Affinity Propagation.  That's an option as well.